# Adding grouping banner to a SharePoint view with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, site-column, power-automate, grouping

I want to group few rows from a SharePoint list based on their value from a specific column (let's call it Column 1). I've read some examples about this but what I can't do is not the grouping of the columns, but how to make it show on the SharePoint list.
There is already a way to make grouping directly from SharePoint site, but I want to automate it with a flow from Power Automate.

Here the SharePoint aggregation I want to automate: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7
If you try out the previous link tutorial, you will understand better the thing I want to automate and the request I'm making.

Thank you and best regard

Edit:this is an example screenshot of what I'm trying to automate from Power Automate and make it show on Sharepoint
[image]

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of what you are trying to do, please? It's a little unclear what you trying to do

Comment: I've just edited the main post so I can be more clear, I hope. I've already performed a grouping on the SharePoint list on power automate, now I need to "make it show" on SharePoint like the picture above (literally just show the "Email Date: [Date] header with the rows underneath referencing to it). I think I need to just edit the list view? Are there any API to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, Power Automate does not have built-in functionality to edit SharePoint list view. Event REST API does not supports GROUP BY functionality.

Comment: So you're saying that even if I've already performed a grouping in Power Automate, I can't make it show on my list view in SharePoint? Is there another way to do so without APIs?

Comment: I've read this [article](https://piyushksingh.com/2016/11/21/retrieve-grouped-listitems-sharepoint/) but I don't know how to use their code snippets in Power Automate. Any idea?

Comment: @user95381. Power Automate cannot edit list view settings with built-in actions, you can check all the available actions inside and there is available ones for updating  view settings. All we have is get list views. Besides rest api, I do not have an idea about other updating approaches in Power Automate. The article you mentioned are using applications to update. You can post the question in Power Automate tech community for possible solutions.